# How to transfer ownership of an account to another EOS key pair?

Tags: accounts

Suppose `account aaa` is associated with `pubkey1`. Is there a way to completely transfer ownership of `account aaa` to another public key `pubkey2` ? The desired result is only `pubkey2` can be used to authorize actions while `pubkey1` can't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Original `fff` account's owner key and active key are `EOS4zQiTie***tBQ4`.

```
bob@bob-VirtualBox:~/eosio-wallet$ cleos get account fff
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS4zQiTiebtvcQqUe1t2Bkn4aLZcdRWR5NcqAZ4bsXxHyBP1tBQ4
        active     1:    1 EOS4zQiTiebtvcQqUe1t2Bkn4aLZcdRWR5NcqAZ4bsXxHyBP1tBQ4
memory: 
     quota:       unlimited  used:      2.66 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited
```

First update owner key.

```
bob@bob-VirtualBox:~/eosio-wallet$ cleos set account permission fff owner EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV -p fff@owner
executed transaction: dbe50e1f6c350d46c1b75fc9815776c7347a3b5e37bf9f6723ae8a316f0616b8  160 bytes  177 us
#         eosio <= eosio::updateauth            {"account":"fff","permission":"owner","parent":"","auth":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS6MRyAjQq8...
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet
```

And now let's query `fff`'s account.

```
bob@bob-VirtualBox:~/eosio-wallet$ cleos get account fff
    permissions: 
         owner     1:    1 EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
            active     1:    1 EOS4zQiTiebtvcQqUe1t2Bkn4aLZcdRWR5NcqAZ4bsXxHyBP1tBQ4
    memory: 
         quota:       unlimited  used:      2.66 KiB  

    net bandwidth: 
         used:               unlimited
         available:          unlimited
         limit:              unlimited

    cpu bandwidth:
         used:               unlimited
         available:          unlimited
         limit:              unlimited
```

As you can see, owner key already updated. Now update active key.

```
bob@bob-VirtualBox:~/eosio-wallet$ cleos set account permission fff  active '{"threshold": 1, "keys": [{"key": "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV", "weight": 1}], "accounts": []}' owner
executed transaction: 8f39cb0171e3cd3ebf2dbd848f73d1cade0cccee9a2a15bc4e2484335d9cce17  160 bytes  208 us
#         eosio <= eosio::updateauth            {"account":"fff","permission":"active","parent":"owner","auth":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS6MR...
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet
```

Let's query `fff`'s account.

```
bob@bob-VirtualBox:~/eosio-wallet$ cleos get account fff
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
        active     1:    1 EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
memory: 
     quota:       unlimited  used:      2.66 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited
```

By now, the account `fff` is transfered from `EOS4zQiTie***tBQ4` key's owner to `EOS6MRyAj***5GDW5CV` key's owner, now it has nothing to do with `EOS4zQiTie***tBQ4`, `EOS6MRyAj***5GDW5CV` has full control of `fff`.

Comment: Hi @spartucus, is it possible to perform the same action that you've outlined above from within a smart contract rather than using cleos?  If so, do you happen to have a code example of that?